# What is the A* time complexity and how is it derived?

Tags: time, complexity-theory, a-star

I was wondering if anyone could explain the A* time complexity.
I am using a heuristic that uses euclidean distance for the estimate of the weight. There are no loops in the heuristic function.
So i think that the time complexity of the heuristic is O(1).

Taking this into account, what would the A* complexity be and how is that derived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can have your answer here:
[Why is the complexity of A* exponential in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715401/why-is-the-complexity-of-a-exponential-in-memory)

time complexity is like memory complexity