# How to compute the running time of A-star algorithm

Tags: performance, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I am working with A* algorithm. I have a 2D grid, with some obstacles, and given the starting and final position, I find the shortest path between them.

Here's my pseudocode

```
while(queueNotEmpty){
  removeFromPQ;
  if(removed == destination)
    found;
  insertAllNeighbours;
}
```

Remove and insert are the function on priority queue(Heap), and is O(log(n)) time.

Considering the dimension of grid as N*N. How do I calculate the running time. i.e how many times will this loop execute? Is there any measure?

Comment: Here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/systrace.html

and here: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/debugging/ddms.html

You will find some information, hope it helps!

Comment: It depends on the end-points and obstacles, so I'm not sure this question is answerable.

Comment: The complexity is drastically dependend on your heuristic, what your pseudo code describes is actually Dijkstras algorithm which runs in O((|V|+|E|)*log(|V|) which is also the worst case of A*.

Comment: @harold lets say that the obstacles are perpendicular lines, but are not specific. So there's no way I could actually find an upper bound on the run time?

Comment: Does that mean the obstacles could separate the start and goal so there is no route? In that case it would explore the entire area reachable from the start position.

Comment: @harold no, that will never happen. I am not sure how to calculate the  the time complexity. The add/removing from heap will take around log(numberOfelementsInHeap)  time, and how many times will the loop execute? n^2 could be the maximum time, for the worst case maybe, but what about the average case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Runtime of standard A* is exponential in the length of the solution (worst-case).

If you're searching on a grid of `n*n`, and you use graph-search, the search will visit each node  at most once; so it's `O(n*n)`. But the found solution will only be optimal if the used heuristic is [monotone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) (in addition to being admissible).

There are also [conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Complexity) for polynomial runtime of standard A*.

For Graph-Search vs. Tree-Search see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15281447/108915).